# lists contain few types Scala

Tags: scala, types

I am relatively new to Scala and I'm currently working on a function that will process a list containing both Strings and Integers.

My desired functionality is as follows:

If the list item is a String, I want to print the string.
If the list item is an Integer, I want to increment it by 2 and then print the resulting number.
Here's a simple function that I've written to handle this task:

```
def processList(list: List[Any]): Unit = {
  list.foreach {
    case i: Int => println(s"Int: $i")
    case s: String => println(s"String: $s")
    case _ => println("Unknown type")
  }
}
```

However, I would like to refine this approach further. Specifically, I want to avoid using the general 'Any' type and make the code more concise and type-safe if possible.

Additionally, I need to be able to call the function in this manner:

```
processList(List("str1", 10, "str2", 20))
```

Any assistance or suggestions on how to better structure this function while retaining the same functionality would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are in **Scala 3** you may use union types, if you are in **Scala 2** but you have **Shapelesss**, you may use co-products . - Peronally, I would either just use `Either` or a custom ADT.

Comment: how to do it with custom ADT?

Answer (score 3):

Using `Any` is not a good choice. As you can see in your own example, you have to ask what type is the value and then you can do whatever you need. Also you have to add a generic case to catch all the possibles types that you can receive. From the end user perspective, any value can be used. An `Int`, an `String` and any other type of value such as a `Boolean`, an `Option`, any type of collection (`List`, `Map`, `Set`, etc), or a custom class created by the user. It could be confusing for the one who call the function and the one who implements it have to create a defense mechanism against something unexpected.

- [SHOULD NOT use Any or AnyRef or isInstanceOf / asInstanceOf](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/v1.1/sections/2-language-rules.md#212-should-not-use-any-or-anyref-or-isinstanceof--asinstanceof)

---

As it was suggested, using ADT is an option. Here you have a couple of atricles that explain how ADT work in scala:

- [Rock the JVM - Algebraic Data Types (ADT) in Scala](https://blog.rockthejvm.com/algebraic-data-types/)
- [Baeldung - Algebraic Data Types in Scala 2](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/algebraic-data-types)
- [ADT in scala 3](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-adts-gadts.html)

Using ADT based on the code provided as example, it should look like:

```scala
sealed trait Data
case class Number(num: Int) extends Data
case class Word(str: String) extends Data

val list: Seq[Data] = List(Number(1), Word("a"), Word("b"), Number(2))

list.foreach {
  case Number(num) => println(s"num: ${num + 2}")
  case Word(str) => println(s"string: $str")
}
```

As any approach, there is always a trade off.

Good when:

- Your data structure will not change in the future and you need to apply different logic based on the data type.

Bad when:

- You need to add new Sum Types frequently. For example, in a near future your system evolves and now needs to handle `Boolean` and `Double`. Your ADT will be like

  ```scala
  sealed trait Data
  case class Number(num: Int) extends Data
  case class Word(str: String) extends Data
  case class Bool(bool: Boolean) extends Data
  case class Decimal(dec: Double) extends Data

  val list: Seq[Data] = List(
     Number(1), 
     Word("a"), 
     Bool(true), 
     Decimal(2.0)
  )

  list.foreach {
     case Number(num) => println(s"num: ${num + 2}")
     case Word(str) => println(s"string: $str")
     case Bool(bool) => ???
     case Decimal(dec) => ???
  }
  ```

  If this is the only place where you use this ADT in your system, it should not be a problem refactor this. If it is used in many places and you apply pattern matching everywhere, when you add a new Sum type you will just get a warning form the compiler. You can force the compiler to give you an error and abort the compilation using the flag `-Xfatal-warnings`. This technique makes the end user check the type of each value and do something with that.

---

You can think in a base class/trait and then create subtypes. Something like

```scala
trait DataObject {
  def doSomething: Unit
}

case class NumberOject(num: Int) extends DataObject {
  override def doSomething: Unit = println(s"Num: ${num + 2}")
}

case class WordOject(str: String) extends DataObject {
  override def doSomething: Unit = println(s"string: $str")
}
```

And this is how you can process the list

```scala
val listObject: Seq[DataObject] = List(
  NumberOject(1),
  WordOject("a"),
  WordOject("b"),
  NumberOject(2)
)
listObject.foreach(obj => obj.doSomething)
```

With this approach, if you create a new subtype and add it to the list, first you have to implement the method `doSomething`. Without that, the code will not compile.

---

Using a type class is another possible technique that can be used to solve everything at compile time.

- [Baeldung - type class](https://nrinaudo.github.io/scala-best-practices/unsafe/structural_types.html)
- [avoid structural types](https://nrinaudo.github.io/scala-best-practices/unsafe/structural_types.html)

```scala
trait ShowTypeClass[A] {
  def show(a: A): Unit
}

case class ShowableWrapper[A](value: A)(implicit showTypeClass: ShowTypeClass[A]){
  def show: Unit = showTypeClass.show(value)
}
```

And this is how you will populate and process the list

```scala
def processShowableList(list: List[ShowableWrapper[_]]) =
  list.foreach(x => x.show)

implicit val showIntTypeClass = new ShowTypeClass[Int] {
  override def show(int: Int): Unit = println(s"num ${int + 2}")
}

implicit val showStringTypeClass = new ShowTypeClass[String] {
  override def show(string: String): Unit = println(s"String: $string")
}

val list: List[ShowableWrapper[_]] = List(ShowableWrapper(1), ShowableWrapper("a"))

processShowableList(list)
```

now each time you want to add a new type, you have to had a type class defined in the scope to know show it

---

Shapeless is another possible approach but I think it will be an overengineered solution for this problem. Here you have a couple of articles that talk about how to use it:

- [Baeldung - Introduction to shapeless](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/generic-programming)
- [Julien Tournay - Getting started with Shapeless](https://jto.github.io/articles/getting-started-with-shapeless/)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez.

My first option would be to use standard Scala types like `Either`, ie `Left` or `Right`, it is also an ADT.

```scala
import scala.util.*

def processList(list: List[Either[String, Int]]): Unit = {
  list.foreach {
    case Right(i) => println(s"Int: $i")
    case Left(s) => println(s"String: $s")
  }
}

processList(List(Right(1), Left("2")))
```

Here's a [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/B1t2jopQTgSVdUQwCcbWRQ)

Comment: I don't want to use Right and Left because I already have a lot of places in my code that call processList(List("str1", "str2", )) and I just want to extend the option for Strings.

Comment: You're kinda asking how to get rid of the `Any` type but still have a `List[Any]` then?!

Comment: You can create small helper methods to convert from `List[String]` to `List[Left[String]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Re. something you said in the comments:

> I don't want to use Right and Left because I already have a lot of places in my code that call processList(List("str1", "str2", )) and I just want to extend the option for Strings.

If I understand correctly what you mean (assuming, that you mistyped "Strings" for "Ints"), you have a function `processList` that accepts a list of strings, and you now want similar functionality for `Int` as well.

Depending on what specifically you want that function to do, an *overload* might be a good option for that. For example, to do what you describe in the question:

```
def processList(lst: List[String]): Unit = lst.foreach(println)
def processList(lst: List[Int]): Unit = processList(
   lst.iterator.map(_ + 2).map(_.toString).toList
)
```

But if you want different types mixed in the same list, then yeah, as others pointed out, the only three possibilities are (1) Any (2) Either or (3) a custom ADT

With (2) or (3) you could theoretically make an implicit conversion to happen automatically, so that `List("foo", 1)` becomes `List(Left("foo"), Right(1))` ...